# Chromium on Linux - All downloaded files have .bin extension

Tags: chrome, browser, mime-types

This is a strange problem and I can't find any info on it. I'm using chromium-browser on Ubuntu 16.04. Whenever I download a file, no matter what type of file it's meant to be, chromium wants to save it as .bin. It doesn't even show what the original extension was supposed to be.

Comment: Are you using KDE?

Comment: The same happens to me with Vivaldi, Chrome in KDE Neon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I quickly found the answer. Silly thing I didn't notice. You have to uncheck automatic file type selection...

[image]

Comment: even after unselected i have it :/

Comment: Yeah but after doing that, you can at least select the proper file extension when you go to download a file. It will still default to .bin but the dropdown also contains the correct one. I don't know how to make it default to the correct one.